# Why git add -A doesn't add all my png files?

Tags: ios, git, git-add

I have a repo containing a bunch of `.png` files. Those are organized into two subdirectories

- `icon/`
- `screen/`

[image]

[image]

As you may notice, they are icons and screens for an iOS app (I don't know if it an useful info).

I perform a `git init` and a `git add -A`.

PNG files in `screen/` get tracked.
PNG files in `icon/` remain untracked.

This is my global `.gitignore`

```
*.retry

# Dropbox settings and caches
.dropbox
.dropbox.attr
.dropbox.cache

# Logs
logs
*.log
npm-debug.log*

# Runtime data
pids
*.pid
*.seed
*.pid.lock

# Directory for instrumented libs generated by jscoverage/JSCover
lib-cov

# Coverage directory used by tools like istanbul
coverage

# nyc test coverage
.nyc_output

# Grunt intermediate storage (http://gruntjs.com/creating-plugins#storing-task-files)
.grunt

# node-waf configuration
.lock-wscript

# Compiled binary addons (http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html)
build/Release

# Dependency directories
node_modules
jspm_packages

# Optional npm cache directory
.npm

# Optional eslint cache
.eslintcache

# Optional REPL history
.node_repl_history

# Output of 'npm pack'
*.tgz

# Yarn Integrity file
.yarn-integrity


# Ignore redis binary dump (dump.rdb) files

*.rdb

# cache files for sublime text
*.tmlanguage.cache
*.tmPreferences.cache
*.stTheme.cache

# workspace files are user-specific
*.sublime-workspace

# project files should be checked into the repository, unless a significant
# proportion of contributors will probably not be using SublimeText
# *.sublime-project

# sftp configuration file
sftp-config.json

# Package control specific files
Package Control.last-run
Package Control.ca-list
Package Control.ca-bundle
Package Control.system-ca-bundle
Package Control.cache/
Package Control.ca-certs/
bh_unicode_properties.cache

# Sublime-github package stores a github token in this file
# https://packagecontrol.io/packages/sublime-github
GitHub.sublime-settings

.vagrant/

# Virtualenv
# http://iamzed.com/2009/05/07/a-primer-on-virtualenv/
.Python
[Bb]in
[Ii]nclude
[Ll]ib
[Ll]ib64
[Ll]ocal
[Ss]cripts
pyvenv.cfg
.venv
pip-selfcheck.json

# Xcode
#
# gitignore contributors: remember to update Global/Xcode.gitignore, Objective-C.gitignore & Swift.gitignore

## Build generated
build/
DerivedData/

## Various settings
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata/

## Other
*.moved-aside
*.xccheckout
*.xcscmblueprint

*.DS_Store
.AppleDouble
.LSOverride

# Icon must end with two \r
Icon


# Thumbnails
._*

# Files that might appear in the root of a volume
.DocumentRevisions-V100
.fseventsd
.Spotlight-V100
.TemporaryItems
.Trashes
.VolumeIcon.icns
.com.apple.timemachine.donotpresent

# Directories potentially created on remote AFP share
.AppleDB
.AppleDesktop
Network Trash Folder
Temporary Items
.apdisk
```

This is my local `.gitignore`

```
build/
.retry
```

I also tried to run `git check-ignore -v *` to find which `.gitignore` rule prevents icon png files to be tracked but there are no rules:

```
.gitignore:1:build/ build
/Users/me/.gitignore_global:1:*.retry   copy_resources.retry
```

I also tried to inspect extended attributes using `ls -al@` but I could'nt spot any differences.

Can you explain why and provide a solution, please?

Comment: From which location did you actually do `git add -A`?  Also, as a side note, it is generally a good idea to avoid versioning binary files in Git, though versioning a few small icons isn't such a bad thing.

Comment: I do `git add -A` from the project root.

Comment: Maybe check your `.gitignore` just as a sanity check.

Comment: My `.gitignore` files (both global and local) don't ignore them. I edited my question to add content from both files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did some testing locally with your setup, on line 133 of your gitignore you have the line

```
Icon
```

This is causing the directory to be ignored.

Decide if you need this rule, if you don't remove that line and re-run

```
git add -A
```

An alternative would be to rename your directory

EDIT: To clarify how I identified this I used

```
git check-ignore -v icon/test1.png
```

which returned

```
.gitignore:133:Icon icon/test1.png
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter. It works! It's very strange I couldn't spot it using `git check-ignore -v *` and it's also very strange git is case insensitive. As far as I know, git is case sensitive by default

Comment: @AdrianoDiGiovanni: Git tries (not always very successfully) to understand whether the host system does case-folding. MacOS HFS+ does case folding by default, so Git sets `core.ignoreCase` to `true` and then knows that `icon` matches `Icon`.